# Modified 2-3-4 tree - algorithms

Tags: algorithm, tree, 2-3-4-tree

I haven 2-3-4 tree but it's modified that only leaves has values. I am not sure if leaves is exact words. Leaves (in my description) are nodes at bottom of tree with maximum depth (these are nodes at the end of tree). Each leave has one value. Other nodes (not leaves) has "value" of smallest value of his children nodes. So this is valid tree:

```
      2
    /   \
  3      2
/ | \  / | \
8 3 4  7 2  5
```

I need to write a few pseudocodes which has maximal complexity O(log n). I have to write minimum (returns minimum from tree), insert(k) (insert new leave with k value), decrease key (x,k) (change key in list x to k), delete (x) remove leave from tree and extract min (remove leave with minimal value).

I've tried to write something on my own but I am not sure if I am doing this right and if I satisfy condition with complexity.

```
class Node234 {
int value;
int count;
Node234 []childrens;
Node234 parent;
}

Node234 minimum()
{
  minimum(root);
}

Node234 minimum(Node234 node)
{
  if(node.count == 0)
  {
    return node;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < node.count; i++)
  {
     if(node.value == node.childrens[i].value)
        return minimum(node.childrens[i]);
  }
}

insert(int newValue)
{
  insert(newValue, root);
}

insert(int newValue, Node234 node)
{
  if(node.count == 0)
  {
    Node234 newNode = new Node234(newValue);
    insert(newNode, newValue, node);
  }
  else
  {
     insert(newValue, node.childrens[node.count-1]);
  }
}

insert(Node234 newNode, int newValue, Node234 node)
{
if(node.parent == null)
{
  Node234 newNodeParent = new Node234(newValue);
  newNodeParent.childrens[0] = node;
  node.parent = newNodeParent;
  newNodeParent.childrens[1] = newNode;
  newNode.parent = newNodeParent;
  if(node.value < newNode.value)
    newNodeParent.value = node.value;
}
else
{
  if(node.parent.count == 4) 
  {
     Node234 newNodeParent = new Node234(newValue);
     node.parent.count--;
      if(node.parent.value == node.value)
      {
         setMinForNode(node.parent);
      }
      newNodeParent.childrens[0] = node;
      node.parent = newNodeParent;
      newNodeParent.childrens[1] = newNode;
      newNode.parent = newNodeParent;

      if(node.value < newValue)
        newNodeParent.value = node.value;
      insert(newNodeParent, newNode.value, node.parent);
  }
  else
  {
    node.parent.childrens[node.parent.count] = newNode;
      node.parent.count++;
      if(newNode.value < node.parent.value)
      {
        changeAllParentKeys(newNode, newNode.value);
      }
  }
}
}

changeAllParentKeys(Node234 node, int newValue)
{
  if(node.parent != null && node.parent.value > newValue)
  {
    node.parent.value = newValue;
    changeAllParentKeys(node.parent, newValue);
  }
}

setMinForNode(Node234 parent)
{
  parent.value = parent.childrens[0].value;
  for(i = 1; i < parent.count; i++)
  {
     if(parent.value > parent.childrens[i].value)
        parent.value = parent.childrens[i].value;
  }
}
```

I hope minimum function is okay but is it insert function okay? Isn't too complex? Could you help me with satisfy complexity condition? Can you help me with other functions (algorithm in words would be enough :) ).

Comment: Can you add a few comments to your code? It's rather difficult to follow as is. If it's pseudo-code, can you make it a bit more pseudo-code-y - hide a few of the low-level details and just give a high-level description of what you're doing - admittedly it's a bit difficult to find the perfect balance between sufficient low-level details and readability, but pseudo-code shouldn't be such a low-level that it looks like it might be compilable. If it's actually written in some language, please add a language tag.

Comment: You mention that "leaves (in my description) are nodes at bottom of tree with maximum depth". This, combined with not storing values in non-"leaves", and ambiguity as to which side inserts / deletes should actually go to, leaves how to do inserts / deletes / rebalancing fairly unclear. Can you elaborate a bit on how exactly this should work?

Comment: First comment to pseudocode. You're right I could write it more without low-level details. It works like it goes to most-right leave and then try to add new value to it's parent. If parent has 4 children then it get 4th children and add it to new node. Like this it's going to top. If root has 4 children then I create new root. Now to second comment. It's not in some order. It just works as I describe (leaves with values, nodes in tree has value as smallest value of leaves). Insert should work like add leave and change values of nodes if need. Delete has link to exact live (it's x).